# Не работает вставка utf8 символов в mssql из-под Апача

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, apache, perl, utf-8

Есть сайт написанный на Perl, работает на старой версии Ubuntu server. Начали переезд на новую версию сервера и сделали тестовую инсталяцию на убунте 20.04. Столкнулись с тем, что вставка utf8 символов в mssql базу не работает если скрипт выполнен Апачем. Если из терминала - работает.

Perl code:

```
my $dbh = get_dbh();
my $str = "xx\x{439}\x{446}\x{443}\x{43a}\x{435}\x{43d}xx";

my $sql = "INSERT INTO [NameValue]([Name],[ValueStr])VALUES('testname', N'$str')";
do_sql($dbh, $sql);
$dbh->commit();

sub get_dbh {
        
    my $datasource = "Docia";
    my $cs = "dbi:ODBC:$datasource";
    
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($cs, 'user', 'pwd', {RaiseError=>0,AutoCommit=>0})
        or die "Database connection not made: ";
    
    $dbh->{LongReadLen} = $read_length;
    $dbh->{odbc_utf8_on}=1;
    $dbh->{odbc_default_bind_type}=SQL_WVARCHAR;

    return $dbh;
}
```

/etc/odbc.ini:

```
[Docia]
DRIVER = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
# SERVER = [protocol:]server[,port]
SERVER = tcp:xxxxxxx,1433
DATABASE=docia-test
APP=Microsoft Windows Operating System
Description=DSA
```

Выполняя из терминала, получаю строку "**xxйцукенxx**". Если через Апач, то становится "**xxÐ¹ÑÑÐºÐµÐ½xx**".

Пытался вызвать скрипт из терминала под апачевским юзером:
sudo -u www-data perl testdbinsert.pl
Так тоже вставляет правильно. Используются одни и те-же библиотечные функции для получения хендлера и выполнения sql. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Я не знаком с перлом, но не увидел в вашем коде ни единого упоминания в какой кодировке вы хотите соединится с БД и в какой именно кодировке сохранен ваш файл/ 
Полагаю вам нужно сделать как сказано здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205727/set-dsn-encoding-for-odbc-driver-11-for-sql-server-on-windows-10 но там винда,.... как на линуксах - незнаю

Comment: Кодировка передачи задается этими строками: $dbh->{odbc_utf8_on}=1; $dbh->{odbc_default_bind_type}=SQL_WVARCHAR;. Кодировка файла в нашем случае значения не имеет, так как я задаю юникодные символы через коды типа "\x{443}". Наверняка еще в самой системе есть где-то указание локали, но я не настолько разбираюсь в линуксе чтоб это найти :( Ну а самое главное что из терминала то работает! Я думал что есть разница в пользователе. Но смена пользователя апача на моего не помогла, равно как и вызов скрипта от www-data ничего не поламал.

Answer (score 0):

А как вы проверяете результат? Вы там точно получаете строку, а не октеты? Другими словами, убедитесь, что в строке ответа поднят флаг `utf8`. Сделайте что-то вроде `use Devel::Peek; Dump $str;` и проверьте ответ.
Для исходной строки получается что-то вроде:

```
SV = PV(0x5587f9740ce0) at 0x5587f977bf90
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x5587f98e73a0 "xx\320\271\321\206\321\203\320\272\320\265\320\275xx"\0 [UTF8 "xx\x{439}\x{446}\x{443}\x{43a}\x{435}\x{43d}xx"]
  CUR = 16
  LEN = 18
  COW_REFCNT = 1
```

Если флага нет, то попробуйте сделать что-то вроде `use Encode qw(decode); $str = decode('utf8', $str);`.

Comment: Ну, с этого я начал. Конечно там поднят флаг. Заметьте: строка вставляется коректно если я вызываю скрипт через терминал: "perl testdbinsert.pl". А вот если я его вызываю через Апач то символы ломаются. У меня уже был схожий случай пару лет назад. Но тогда не только запись, но и чтение из базы давало неверные символы. Вылечилось патчем "/etc/apache2/envvars": написал "LANG=en_US.UTF-8". Тогда это помогло. Сейчас я это тоже попробовал. Как можно догадаться, без результата.

Comment: Локаль тут явно не причём. А у вас сборка драйверов без поддержки юникода, верно? Иначе, параметры лишние. Если так, то я бы сделал следующее: или собрал бы драйвера с поддержкой оного и отказался от параметров(это описано в документации), или попробовал перед передачей преобразовать строку в октеты:
`$str = encode('utf8', $str);`

Comment: Я бы согласился что проблема с драйвером если бы оно не работало вообще. Но из терманала скрипт все вставляет правильно! А вот если этот скрипт вызвать через апач - нет. Так что остается подозревать нечто специфичное для пользователя: переменные окружения например.

Comment: И вот еще: если использовать параметризованный запрос типа "insert into namevalue(name. valuestr) values(?,?)" и передать параметры в sth то это всегда работает правильно. Но я не могу просто взять и все порефакторить: даже с точки зрения времени это займет месяцы. Надо найти решение как есть.